# Android studio design screen scrolling top on every change

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to constraintlayouts.
I have constraintlayout in scrollview. When I'm designing the bottom of the screen (so i can't see top of the screen), on every change (moving an imageview) scrollview scrolls to top.
So i go back to bottom of the screen for continue to design again and again.

Maybe studio rendering the view and resets but it makes the designing hard.

Here is the video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zZQBqPmMew&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm new to Android Studio and this is very annoying. I'm in a split view with XML on the left and the preview on the right, and when editing the XML towards the bottom the preview is scrolling to the top on every change!

Comment: @Nathan unfortunately no. So I design every layout in different XML's, and I use/collect them in one screen.

Answer (score 4):

Make Size custom as i shown in 1st image

then just adjust size as i shown in second picture
then u r done :)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks @ Vaibhav Pallod, This is what I needed.
Shold be accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

In scroll view:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Change this to

```
android:layout_height="3500dp"//any number higher than your expected height of scrollview
```

After you complete designing, you can change this tho "`wrap_content`"

It's worked for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Unheilig...the first time i used this method..i found its working...but its not working now..why?:( ...can i delete this answer..im new here...

Answer (score 0):

One trick I used is I just expand the size of the screen vertically. You can "resize" the screen for different devices, I just pretend to android studio that my phone is actually a foot long, or at least for just this activity.
Its definitely hacky, but I haven't found a better method yet.